# How to remove empty place in Facebook sharing in Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook, facebook-share

I am sharing an image,text and a link to Facebook.If an image URL is available it correctly shows all the values while sharing.If an image URL is not available means a default image is automatically taken and shared with that text and image.How to avoid the displaying default image.I used the above code for that.

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(
                    SocialSharing.this).setLink(pop_Link)
                    .setName(tweet_Message).build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

If I used setPicture method in the code and set the given link as i used for setLink method,while sharing a white place holder is showed at left in Facebook (please see the image).

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog1 = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(
            SocialSharing.this).setLink(pop_Link)
            .setPicture(pop_Link).setName(tweet_Message).build();
............

uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog1.present());
```

[image]

Comment: why do you not want to show an image? Do you own the URL that you're sharing?

Comment: have you solved this ?